# Can't change font size of label in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to build a very simple form. It all works fine except I need to dynamically draw a label onto the form. I can draw the label, but when I try and change the `newlabel.Font.Size` attribute, I get this error:

```
Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Font.Size' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it? This is my first ever C# program, so please cut me some slack if I'm doing something really stupid.

Here is my code for drawing the label:

```
Label newlabel = new Label();
newlabel.Text = "BOOM";
newlabel.Font.Size = 72;//This causes the error
newlabel.ForeColor = Color.White;
newlabel.Location = new Point(250,250);
newlabel.AutoSize = false;
this.Controls.Add(newlabel);
```

Comment: You'll probably need to create a new `Font` with size `72` and everything else copied from `newlabel.Font` (i.e. the current font).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You have to create a new font using: `newlabel.Font = new Font(fontFamily, size);`

Answer (score 12):

try this

```
newlabel.Font = new Font(newlabel.Font.FontFamily, Fontsize);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Label newlabel = new Label();

newlabel.Font = new System.Drawing.Font(l.Font.FontFamily.Name, 12);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var label1 = new Label();
label1.Font = new Font(new FontFamily(System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies.Serif), 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to explain the following error:

> Property or indexer 'System.Drawing.Font.Size' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

This is a compile-time error regarding the accessibility of a variable. In your example, `System.Drawing.Font.Size` cannot be modified because the property within the `Font` class is declared as `public float Size { get; }`. You're able to view this by right-clicking `Size` and clicking on "*Go to definition*".
The property declaration shown above describes a float value called Size which has a public 'getter' method - meaning you're able to retreive a value from that property.
It has no 'setter' property which makes modification impossible.

Since the property is unable to be changed, you will need to create a new `Font` by changing the `Font` property to something like `new Font("Times New Roman", 12.0f);`. Take a look at the following [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.font(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) which provides all the different constructors for the `Font` class.

A working example is shown below for your convenience:

```
Label newlabel = new Label {
    Text = "BOOM",
    Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 12.0f),
    ForeColor = Color.White,
    Location = new Point(250, 250),
    AutoSize = false
};
this.Controls.Add(newlabel);
```